# Converting varchar to data type numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure `spGetMetricValues` in a sql file. To execute it I have another file has the following:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMetricValues]

  EXECQSG.dbo.EXCEL_FUNC
    @asofdate date,
    @startdate date,
    @coupon_type varchar(25),
    @security_term varchar(25),
    @metric_type varchar(25),
    @whose_holding varchar(25),
    @accretion_type varchar(25),
    @decomp_method varchar(25)

  DECLARE @output decimal(28,10)
  SELECT @output = @query  --@query is defined in the SP as varchar(1000)
  RETURN (ISNULL(@output,0))
END
```

When I execute, I get an error

> Arithmetic Overflow Error Converting varchar to data numeric

Can someone please tell what should I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you wanted to execute the query and not just set `@output` to the query string. But what do you want `@output` to contain?

Comment: Yes, when I try to execute the query, it gives me that overflow error. The @output is a numeric value.

Comment: But you're not executing the query. You're just setting `@output = @query`...

Comment: The code you have above, when I click "Execute" button, I get the overflow error flow. The bottom part might have something wrong.   What I know is this: converting the varchar '@query' into the decimal  '@output'

Answer (score 0):

Return will only accept integer dataType

```
RETURN [int]
```